# .replace() is not replacing elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

new to pandas, learning.
Have a column in my df where I need to replace certain elements in it with specific data.

Daily_Report is my df. I need to replace "LI" and "MC" in my "Country" column with "CH", "FR". I wrote the below which worked at first, but at rerunning the notebook from the beginning in Jupyter notebook, it doesn;t do anything anymore)

```
Daily_Report['Country'].replace('LI', 'CH', inplace=True)
Daily_Report['Country'].replace('MC', 'FR', inplace=True)
Daily_Report['Country'].value_counts()

GB    8132
FR    5811
DE    3390
ES    2280
IT    1930
CH    1516
NL    1414
SE     938
LI      31
MC      24
Name: Country, dtype: int64
```

For a successful replace, LI an MC would not show after running value.counts()
What am I missing here?

Thanks a lot

Comment: `Daily_Report['Country'].replace('LI', 'CH', inplace=True,regex=True)` or `Daily_Report['Country'].str.replace('LI', 'CH', inplace=True)`

Comment: or replace by dict in a single line: `Daily_Report['Country'].replace({'LI':'CH','MC':'FR'},regex=True,inplace=True)`

Comment: How working solutions? There are whitespaces or not?

Answer (score 2):

For me working nice in `pandas 0.24.2`:

```
Daily_Report = pd.DataFrame({ 'Country':['LI','MC','SE','NL']})
Daily_Report['Country'].replace('LI', 'CH', inplace=True)
Daily_Report['Country'].replace('MC', 'FR', inplace=True)
print (Daily_Report)
  Country
0      CH
1      FR
2      SE
3      NL
```

Alternative with [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) and nested dicts - outer specify column for replace and inner mapping:

```
Daily_Report = pd.DataFrame({ 'Country':['LI','MC','SE','NL']})
Daily_Report1 = Daily_Report.replace({'Country':{'LI':'CH','MC':'FR'}})
print (Daily_Report1)
  Country
0      CH
1      FR
2      SE
3      NL
```

Comment: @anky_91 - I think not, because from output data is not necessary substring replacement

Answer (score 2):

```
Daily_Report['Country'].replace('LI', 'CH', inplace=True)
Daily_Report['Country'].replace('MC', 'FR', inplace=True)
```

As you did should work unless 'LI' and 'MC' have tracing or leading whitespaces like
`'LI '` or `' MC`. Try checking if this is the case